# get user confirmation inside a loop

Tags: c#, .net, do-while

After searching for a Solution with a do-while Loop, I'm now stuck and this point, and just cant figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
static void StartUp()
{

    bool confirmChoice = false;

    Console.WriteLine("Hey, Enter your Character Name!");
    string name = Console.ReadLine();
    do
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Is " + name + " correct? (y) or would you like to change it (n)?");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (input == "n")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Allright, enter your new Name then!");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        confirmChoice = true;
    }
    }while(confirmChoice);
}
```

Comment: Your `while(confirmChoice);` should be `while(!confirmChoice);` Your condition is wrong so you're looping when you shouldn't. And vice versa. The `while` condition loops when the condition is `true` which it is in your case when your `input` variable isn't `"n"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost right - all you need to do is inverting the condition of your `do`/`while` loop to `while (!confirmChoice)`

However, you could do better than that: make a forever loop, and use `break` to exit it:

```
while (true) {
    Console.WriteLine("Please, Enter your Character Name!");
    string name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Is " + name + " correct? (y) or would you like to change it (n)?");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (input == "y") {
        break;
    }
}
```

This is a common solution for situations when the decision to exit is made in the middle of the loop body.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me out a great Deal!

Answer (score 1):

you should change the termination condition for your loop
it should be `while(!confirmChoice);`
and  you should change the `break;` line to `continue;`

Answer (score 1):

Your Condition is wrong it should be `while(confirmChoice==false)` and don't use `break;`

```
 static void StartUp()
    {

        bool confirmChoice = false;

        Console.WriteLine("Hey, Enter your Character Name!");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        do
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Is " + name + " correct? (y) or would you like to change it (n)?");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (input == "n")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Allright, enter your new Name then!");
            name = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            confirmChoice = true;
        }
        }while(confirmChoice==false);
    }
```